# Hide a canvas line when a modal is open

Tags: reactjs

I would like to hide a canvas when the modal is opened.

I'm using this modal dependencie:
https://react-responsive-modal.leopradel.com/#example

The parent component contains the canvas.
A child component might make diapear the canvas from the parent component when
the modal is opened.

I tried to do this way in the child component, inside of the openModal function.
And it didn't work.

```
document.querySelector('#canvas').style.display = "none"
```

I have this App component with canvas lines.
This is the parent component.

```
Class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.drawCanvas = this.drawCanvas.bind(this)
  }


  drawCanvas() {
   // here is a code to draw the canvas. 
   // This does not need to be shown
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.drawCanvas()
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <div className="wrapper-all">
          <Coluna1 />
          <Coluna2 />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default App;
```

Therefore I have a child Component that open a modal inside it. this child component might the canvas from the parent component to be disapeared when the modal is opened.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal';   


class Interiores extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)       
      open: false
    }
  }

  onOpenModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });

  //Here is the code that i'm trying to hide 
  //the canvas
    document.querySelector('#canvas').style.display = "none"
  };

  onCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };     

  render() { 
    const { open } = this.state;   
    return (
      <div>     
         <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} center>
           <button onClick={this.onOpenModal}>Open modal</button>            
          <p>   
            modal text here
          </p>
        </Modal>                   
        </div>                  
      </div>
    )
  }      
}

export default Interiores;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is just like that:

```
onOpenModal = () => {
  this.setState({ open: true });
    document.querySelector('#canvas').style.display = 'none'
};

onExited = () => {
   document.querySelector('#canvas').style.display = 'block'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use state uplifting to get the open state into your `App` class and the prevent the drawing of the canvas in render:

https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Add the modalToggled() to your app

```
Class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.drawCanvas = this.drawCanvas.bind(this);
    this.state = {modalOn: false};
  }


  drawCanvas() {
   // here is a code to draw the canvas. 
   // This does not need to be shown
  }

  /** NEW **/
  modalToggled = (on) => {
    this.setState({modalOn: on});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.drawCanvas()
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.modalOn && <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>}
        <div className="wrapper-all">
          <Coluna1 />
          <Coluna2 />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default App;
```

Now change the call of Interiores as follows:

```
<Interiores onModalToggle={this.modalToggled} />
```

Now to your Interiores class, add the calls to the uplifted function:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal';   


class Interiores extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)       
      open: false
    }
  }

  onOpenModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });

    this.props.onModalToggle(true);
  };

  onCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
    this.props.onModalToggle(false);
  };     

  render() { 
    const { open } = this.state;   
    return (
      <div>     
         <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} center>
           <button onClick={this.onOpenModal}>Open modal</button>            
          <p>   
            modal text here
          </p>
        </Modal>                   
        </div>                  
      </div>
    )
  }      
}

export default Interiores;
```

Also instead of binding this to drawCanvas manually you can just declare drawCanvas as a fat arrow function `drawCanvas = () => {}`, you do not need to use .bind() then.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with props.

**Parent Component**

Declare a Boolean property in constructor to show Canvas initially in Parent component -

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.drawCanvas = this.drawCanvas.bind(this);
    this.state = { HideCanvas : false }
  }
```

You have `Interiores` component in parent. Give it a props as

```
{!this.state.HideCanvas && <canvas id="canvas"></canvas> } //initially displaying canvas
<Interiores hideCanvas={() => this.setState({ HideCanvas:true })}/>
```

**Child Component**

```
  onOpenModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true }, () => {
      this.props.hideCanvas(); //this will hide canvas in Parent component by using props.
    });
 };
```

As props are always passed to child components therefore you can have benefits of it many ways. If you note we've declared a function `hideCanvas()` as a prop to Child Component in `App (Parent) Component`.

Now whenever you open the model you can call this method to hide Canvas by calling function of props directly.